# Is it possible to add a value named 'None' to enum type?

Tags: python, enums

can I add a value named 'None' to a enum?
for example

```
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
    None=0 #represent no color at all
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3

color=Color.None

if (color==Color.None):
    #don't fill the rect
else:
    #fill the rect with the color
```

This question is related to my previous question 
[How to set a variable's subproperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686377/how-to-set-a-variables-subproperty)

Of course, I understand the above `None` in `enum` doesn't work.
but from the vendor's code, I do see something like this:
`bird.eye.Color=bird.eye.Color.enum.None`
I checked the `type(bird.eye.Color)`
it is a `<class 'flufl.enum._enum.IntEnumValue'>`
so a `flufl.enum` is used. I suppose it should not be very different to use a `flufl.enum` or a `Enum`.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happened when you tried the above code? Did you get an error message?

Comment: You can't assign to a keyword. `None = *` would throw a `SyntaxError`, but you can use `none = *`.

Comment: @Pythonista is right about none vs. None.

Comment: @georgeandrew: How about not putting a `None` entry in the enum, and instead saying: `color = None` when need be.

Comment: Related, interesting read: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2013/11/story-of-none-true-false.html

Comment: Ah, you're using uncle barry's enum implementation.  This was not accepted into python core, you might want to switch to the official implementation instead (`pip uninstall enum; pip install enum34`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using the `Enum` constructor rather than creating a subclass

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> 
>>> Color = Enum('Color', {'None': 0, 'Red': 1, 'Green': 2, 'Blue': 3})
>>> Color.None
<Color.None: 0
```

EDIT: This works using the `enum34` backport for python 2.  In python 3, you will be able to create the `Enum` with the `None` attribute, but you won't be able to access using dot notation.

```
>>> Color.None
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Oddly, you can still access it with `getattr`

```
>>> getattr(Color, 'None')
<Color.None: 0>
```

Comment: This is only possible in Python 2 because they were more forgiving with the `None` name (it is not present in `keyword.kwlist`).  It's broken in python3.

Comment: @wim  Yeah, I used the `enum34` backport.  It's a bit odd though, because in Python3, it will allow the Enum creation with `None`, but it errors out when trying to access it with `Color.None`.  You can still do `getattr(Color, 'None')` though.

Comment: Not really odd - similar behaviour exists in python 2 aswell.  For example, you can do `setattr(my_obj, 'import', 123)`.  But why would you want to set an attribute that you can't get with normal attribute access?  There is only disadvantage to doing so ..

Comment: Thank you very much@Brendan Abel for suggestions in both python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this directly because it is a syntax error to assign to `None`.

Neither should you set an attribute on your enum class dynamically, because this will interfere with the metaclass logic that `Enum` uses to prepare your class.

You should just use a lowercase name `none` to avoid the name collision with python's `None` singleton.  For the use-case you have described, there is no disadvantage to this approach.

Comment: Brendan Abel's answer looks like it probably works without any side-effects like mine.

Comment: No.  The side-effect is that it doesn't work in python3.

Answer (score -2):

Not quite the way you tried, but you can do this:

```
# After defining the class Color as normal, but excluding the part for None...
setattr(Color, 'None', 0)

color = Color.None
if color == Color.None:
    ...
```

Note: I did this in Python 2. Not sure if you want this in Python 2 or 3 because you didn't specify, and I don't have a copy of Python 3 installed on this machine to test with.

Comment: You can, but you should not.

Comment: To elaborate, this sidesteps the metaclass magic that the Enum class does, so it will not be a proper member of the enum.  That has many unfortunate side-effects, for example won't show up in `list(Color)`, no collision prevention or aliasing possible, etc

Comment: @wim - Is that a standard module in Python 3? I figured the OP had installed something named `enum` using `pip`. Anyways, I'm sure there's something we can do to make all of the magic work.

Comment: Unless specified otherwise, you can assume the core library Enum class (`enum34` backport in python 2.x)