# Pythonnet trouble with enum containing "None"

Tags: python, enums, python.net

Im using pythonnet to work with a C# dll having the following Enum (from doc):

```
 public enum DownloadOptions {
 None = 0, // Download nothing
 Hardware, // Download hardware only 
 Software // Download software only
 }
```

Printing "Hardware" and "software" gives me "1" and "2" while printing "None" i get syntax error.  It also works fine passing "1" or "2" to the C# function requiring this enum, but "0" is not accepted.

My feeling is that the name "None" is causing trouble here as it is a reserved python keyword.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution when I faced the same problem
when I use NationalInstruments.VisaNS.dll in python, I have to access the enum *None* in `NationalInstruments.VisaNS.Parity`, if use `NationalInstruments.VisaNS.Parity.None` always get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, so i change search key words to "pythonnet enum None" and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773832/is-it-possible-to-add-a-value-named-none-to-enum-type) which solve my problem.
So compare to

```
NationalInstruments.VisaNS.Parity.None
```

use

```
getattr(NationalInstruments.VisaNS.Parity,'None')
```

instead.